# modbus: выбор контроллера

Tags: modbus

мне нужно подобрать контроллер, который я смогу подключить к устройствам, которые работают по протоколу ***modbus***, подключить к сети и потом считывать эти данные. может кто сталкивался с этим?

Answer (score 0):

Если вы говорите про modbus rtu устройства, то лучшим устройствам для Вас будет "Moxa mgate"
Данное устройство имеет 485\232 интерфейс с одной стороны и интерфейс Ethernet с другой.

Вы сможете обращаться к устройствам по протоколу modbus tcp по ip адресу устройства mgate + slave адресу устройства в сети rtu.